# Pass a COM object from C# to Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, com

I have a program I wrote in C# that interacts with a propriety COM interface.  Unfortunately, this interface has features that do not work properly with C#.  However, the interface works fine from Visual Basic.

I have already written a lot of code in C# on the parts of the interface that DO work from C#, so I don't really want to rewrite it all in VB if I can avoid it.  I would like to find an easy way to use Visual Basic for the features I do need, without re-writing all the code I already have.  So, the question is, what is the BEST ay to do this?

My first attempt:

I was hoping I could just pass the COM object that I created in C# to Visual Basic and it would work. Like so:

C#:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ACM Application");
acm = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
ACMAccess.ACMAccess acmAccess =new ACMAccess.ACMAccess(acm);
```

VB:

```
Sub New(ByVal acm)
    Dim starVars = acm.Simulation.Flowsheet.FindMatchingVariables("~")

    For Each Var In starVars
        Console.WriteLine(Var.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Sadly, this does not work.  The failure is kind of interesting, in the debugger it has the right type, but if I call a method, it doesn't do anything.  If I try a method name that doesn't exist, I get an exception, but an existing method, nothing happens.

Second idea:

The alternative I can think of, which I've been avoiding for a while, is the delegation pattern.  Create a VB object that actually creates and does all the interaction with the COM interface.  The rest of the C# program would only use the COM interface through the VB wrapper.  (As opposed to passing it back and forth as in the first attempt.)

Comment: I'm interested to know what you can do in VB.NET that you cannot do in C# - could you elaborate please?

Comment: Could you wrap the object in a C# library and call the methods that way? As for the COM object, is it in-house or something else? It sounds like its COM stuff may not have been implemented properly.

Comment: @SteveMayne Option Strict Off in VB.Net is still a little bit nicer for COM interop than using a lot of dynamic in C#.

Comment: Not a real question - "However, now I need a new feature that doesn't work at all with C#. I need to use Visual Basic."

Comment: When you are in charge of both ends and it doesn't work, you are doing something wrong

Comment: Pete: The COM interface is proprietary, I have no access to it.  It is obviously broken in some way, but I don't have access to fix it.  (I'm not sure what good wrapping the object in C# would do?)

Comment: If you've already figured out how to get C# to interact with the COM interface in a satisfactory way, that means you should be able to wrap the COM interaction in C#, and then use that to create a library that you access from VB.NET.

Comment: @Steve Mayne Well, in C# all the exceptions end up being NullReferenceExceptions, where as in VB they are actual errors.
The issue in this case is that the set type doesn't work in C#.  The above call to FindMatchingVariables will return a Set object in C# as well, but any calls to it or attempts to iterate over it will throw an exception.  So it's useless.

Comment: @JLRishe  Right, that's what I'm trying to do, but backwards.  The COM interface works in VB, but has odd behavior in C#.  This question is about the easiest way to make that wrapper library.

Comment: @Jim I think what you described in the final paragraph of your post is the way to go.  Even if it creates more work in the short run, it will mean less headaches for everyone who uses the code in the long run. Interacting with the COM object in both the C# code _and_ the VB code is just cruel to anyone who has to maintain that code. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Jim - I think your VB wrapper idea is the way I'd go.

Comment: And the full VB wrapper is what I ended up doing, it didn't take that long.  I should've done it months ago.